# Centering Custom y-ticks Imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, imshow

I'm trying to center yaxis tick marks on an imshow image similar [to the one here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opr21.png). In the image, each row is a separate "profile" that I've stacked together. I want the tick location to be at the center of each horizontal section, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKQjY.png) (made in Powerpoint).

Here's some working code to make the images above:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
td = [0,1,2,5,10,15,25,66]
N = len(td)
profiles = np.random.randn(N, 501).cumsum(axis=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.imshow(profiles, interpolation='none', aspect='auto', extent=[0, 500, N-1, 0])
ax.set_yticks(range(N))
plt.show()
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Let me know how I can clarify my question. If possible, I'd like to learn how to do this with `matplotlib.axes` (i.e., `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)`...). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set y ticks and tick labels at `0.5`, `1.5` etc. (matplotlib 3.5.0 or above to do this in one call to [`set_ylabel`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html?highlight=set_yticks#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

td = [0,1,2,5,10,15,25,66]
N = len(td)
profiles = np.random.randn(N, 501).cumsum(axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(profiles, interpolation='none', aspect='auto', extent=[0, 500, N, 0])
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(N) + 0.5, [f'{y}' for y in td])
```

[image]